# Regex more than 4 characters containing all except blankspace and new line

Tags: regex

I want a Regex for client side password Html5 validation, with no knowledge of how regex works; I found the best answer in this regex `((?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?!\s).{4,})` but it needs necessary a number. My requirements are:

> Any input more than 4 alpha-numerics or special characters except blank-space and new-line.

Please help!

Comment: You could use the following regex: `^[^\s]{4,}$`

Comment: @Abhisek you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `^\S{5,}$`. It means:

1. Match beginning of input
2. Match a non whitespace character ->

   2.1 As many as possible, but at least 5
3. Match end of input

See snippet:

```js
var passwords = [
  'aa',
  'abcde',
  'ab cd',
  'abcdefg',
  'a1234',
  'a1234 '
];

var rePassword = /^\S{5,}$/

for(var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
  console.log(passwords[i], rePassword.test(passwords[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like `^(?=.*\d)\S{5,}$`, where

`(?=.*\d)` is a positive lookahead asserting the password contains at least 1 digit

`\S{5,}` matches at least 5 non-whitespace characters.

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iR1cL4/3)

Comment: The Op stated "more than 4", so I think he really wants {5,} - no?

Comment: Why would you add a rule that mandates the password contains at least 1 digit? it's not required. In fact, it's wrong considering OP requirements.

Comment: @Amit - the OP said `but it needs necessary a number`

Comment: That's what the regex in OP does, but doesn't fit requirements. Requirements are (very clear): *Any input more than 4 alphanumerics or special character except blankspace and new line*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the requirement of having at least one digit character you might use:

```
    ^([^\s]{4,}[0-9][^\s]*)|([^\s]{3,}[0-9][^\s]+)|([^\s]{2,}[0-9][^\s]{2,})|([^\s]+[0-9][^\s]{3,})|([^\s]*[0-9][^\s]{4,})$
```

(Requires at least 5 non-whitespace characters including at least one digit.)

Well, it's a bit verbouse to do this in regex, I know.